# point to point JMS and publish and subscribe

Tags: jms, distributed, point

I have a basic question about, the JMS architecture. A typical arrangement can be point-to-point, were message from customers are interleaved. that means that concurrent communication is not supported right?

now in publish and subscribe we can have lots of customers registered in one or more topics, and each time a message is sent all the registered customers receive the message right?
(i guess it is done by using multicast right?)

if i wanted to implement JMS for sending queries to a database, and receive responses from the database, then the publish and subscribe method should be used right? I can't do it with point - to - point, if i have multiple client right?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do it with point to point, you just probably wouldn't want to.

For database interactions, you probably want a data grid, not a message queue - and you can use temporary queues if you really are desperate to fit JMS into the architecture.

I guess I have a question for you: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?